# C# code refactoring Background worker

Tags: c#, refactoring

On .NET Windows form, I have Background worker component that works fine. I have 5 forms, that has basically same Background worker on it with same code. 
Can I extract this code to other class and somehow use it, considering this is an event? This is code I have on form. It takes 20 lines of code, and it would be nice if this can be refactored. Note: as you can see, I have already put it to other class BackgroundWorkerHelper, but can I also somehow refactor this events on Background worker, so that it is in other class as well, this way code is less and reused.

```
private void RunBackgroundWorker(string infoLabelText, int imageIndex)
{
    BackgroundWorkerHelper.Run(backgroundWorker, progressBar, infoLabelText, imageIndex);
}

private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorkerHelper.DoWork(backgroundWorker);
}

private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorkerHelper.ProgressChanged(sender, e, progressBar);
}

private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorkerHelper.RunWorkerCompleted(sender, e, progressBar);
}
```

Note: for now I would like to avoid using user control. I know I could do it, but then you have code that handles placing user control and so on. I am still not very good in it.

Comment: Yes, you can put this code in another class.  What is your actual problem?

Comment: well, I could put it to other class, but these are events, how would they fire then, as now they are binded to form control in designer part. How would I pass this backgroundWorker object instance, since it is all in form control designer (events)? Sorry, I am still beginner.

Comment: Don't instantiate the bg worker in the form, instantiate it in your new class instead.  Unfortunately, this site is not for training of beginning coders.  You have to have some base of knowledge as to how to code in the language you're asking about.  You should teach yourself the basics, and if you're still confused about a particular thing, feel free to come back and ask a specific question.

Comment: well, in none tutorial you will find how to code in Windows forms, how to do it, they teach language basics but none of the controls specifics. I am not beginner like I passed few tutorials, I am in coding for about 2 years. These are not basics as you say, not at all. However thank you for your answer, it made me think of possible solution. Thanks

Comment: rory.ap ,  I have done the way you described it, I have done it in a separate class I named BackgroundWorkerHelper.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution, thanks to rory who gave me idea how to do it. First, I made this class:

```
public class BackgroundWorkerHelper
{
    private static string _infoLabelText = string.Empty;
    public BackgroundWorker _BackgroundWorker;
    private BarEditItem _marqueeInfo;//this is marquee progress bar

    public BackgroundWorkerHelper(BarEditItem marqueeInfo)
    {
        _marqueeInfo = marqueeInfo;

        _BackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _BackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        _BackgroundWorker.DoWork += backgroundWorker_DoWork;
        _BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
        _BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    public void Run(string labelText, int imageIndex)
    {
        _marqueeInfo.Caption = labelText;
        _marqueeInfo.ImageIndex = imageIndex;

        if (!_BackgroundWorker.IsBusy)
            _BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        else
            _marqueeInfo.Caption = "Busy processing saving data, please wait...";
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            _BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i); // call backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged event and pass i (which is e argument e.ProgressPercentage) to update UI controls
            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
    }

    public void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _marqueeInfo.Visibility = BarItemVisibility.Always;
    }

    public void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        _marqueeInfo.Visibility = BarItemVisibility.Never;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        DoWork();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressChanged(sender, e);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        RunWorkerCompleted(sender, e);
    }
```

then in FORM, in class level above constructor place

```
private readonly BackgroundWorkerHelper _backgroundWorkerHelper;
```

then in Form Constructor instantiate class

```
_backgroundWorkerHelper = new BackgroundWorkerHelper(marqueeInfo);
```

and then I just call it in my form

```
_backgroundWorkerHelper.Run("Saving", 14);
```